# Append value to FireStore document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am building a chat app. When adding messages to document container in Firestore, it somehow adds in the middle or somewhere else. Since I get them all and display in chat, messages are not sorted according to chronology ( last sent message appears at the beginning). So the question is how to append data in a document?

Comment: Show us a screenshot of that unexpected behavior.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using an `OrderBy` clause on the query, the messages will be sorted by their Document IDs, which I am guessing in your case is the Firestore generated values. If you would like to  order them by most recent, you can add a `Date` field to your messages and do something like

```
messagesCollection.orderBy("date", "desc")
```

See the [Firestore Documentation on ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried OrderBy ?
It seems with this to your firestore queries you can order according to chronology